# How to declare two objects with the same name but different properties

Tags: javascript, xml, javascript-objects

I am working on the function in node.js that creates JS object and then converts it to XML. The xml format template requires to have two properties with the same name but different values, such as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<XMLExample>

<Person id="123ok" type="student">
<searchable>true</searchable>
<valid>true</valid> 
</Person>

<Person name="Aiana" type="student" parentPersonId="123ok">
<lastName>Ali</lastName>
<grade>9</grade>
<gradYear>2020</gradYear>
</Person>

</XMLExample>
```

Question is how to set up two 'Person' JS objects of the same name inside another object?

```
var futureXMLObject = {
      "Person": {
      "@id": "123ok",
      "@type": "student"
       ...
      }
    }

    "Person": {
     "@name": "Aiana",
     "@type": "student",
     "@parentPersonId": "123ok"
     ...
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. How would you access the objects in the object? `futureXMLObject['Person']` would not work as it can't return two objects.

Have you thought about using an array?

```
var futureXMLObj = {
    "Persons": [
        {
            "@id": "123ok",
            "@type": "student"
        },
        {
            "@name": "Aiana",
            "@type": "student",
            "@parentPersonId": "123ok"
        }
    ]
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like an array of objects instead of only one object

Comment: That's a comment, not an answer. It would be an answer if you provided a code  example of what you suggest.

Answer (score 0):

you can't do that, but you can use an `Array` of objects

```
var futureXMLObject = {
  "Person": [
    {
      "@id": "123ok",
      "@type": "student"
     },
     {
       "@name": "Aiana",
       "@type": "student",
     }
   ]
}
for (var person of futureXMLObject['Person']) {
  console.log(person);
}
```

Comment: Technically it's correct, but the `"Person"` key name annoys me. By convention, since it's an array containing several `Person`, it should be called `Persons`.